# keep loading to build android APK on windows in Phonegap hybrid application

Tags: android, cordova, sdk

I have followed below URL for setting up the android sdk. Everything set perfectly. But, when i try to build the APK via CLI, It is keep on loading.
Documentation link
[phonegap documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/4.0.0/guide_platforms_android_index.md.html)

Below is the message it is showing.

```
 E:\Ahamed\hybrid\MyFirstHybrid>cordova build
 Discovered plugin "cordova-plugin-dialogs" in config.xml. Adding it to the project
 Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-dialogs@~1.2.0" via npm
 Installing "cordova-plugin-dialogs" for android
 ANDROID_HOME=F:\project\sdk
 JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\java\jdk1.8.0_101
 Subproject Path: CordovaLib
 Starting a new Gradle Daemon for this build (subsequent builds will be faster).
 Configuring > 0/2 projects > root project > Resolving dependencies ':classpath'
```

Help will be appreciated and up voted. Thank you.